# Operand type clash: image is incompatible with xml Error

Tags: python, sql, xml, t-sql, pyodbc

I am getting the below error *'Operand type clash: image is incompatible with xml'* , when i follow the exact same instructions as below

[Store XML File into MS SQL DB using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58881041/19907888)

Here is my code

```
import pyodbc
#import xlrd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
from lxml import etree

os.chdir("C:/Users/tasks/xml_Parsing")

print("Connecting..")
# Establish a connection between Python and SQL Server
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    Trusted_Connection='Yes',
    Driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',
    Server='10.x.x.xxx',
    Database='Out'
)



# Get XMLFile
XMLFilePath = open('00A1222H001.xml')
x = etree.parse(XMLFilePath)          
#print(x)

with open("00A1222H001.xml", "wb") as f:      
    f.write(etree.tostring(x))         

    #print(x)

cursor = cnxn.cursor() 


InsertQuery = """INSERT INTO dbo.Xml_test (XBRLFile) values(?)""" 


# Assign values from each row
values = etree.tostring(x) # Updated Code line

#print(values)

# Execute SQL Insert Query
cursor.execute(InsertQuery, values)

# Commit the transaction
cnxn.commit()

# Close the database connection
cnxn.close()
```

My error

[image: er]

Kindly help me. This is my first time to deal with xml files.

Comment: Add the full traceback message so we see where it failed.

Comment: @tdelaney - failed at insert query, screenshot added in the question

Comment: What is `type(values)`? Is it `<class 'bytes'>`?

Comment: @ Gord Thompson - Yes it is of class bytes